# Pythonic way to simple array handling

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[2,0,1,2,0],[0,1,2,0,1],[2,0,1,2,2]])
```

I require the following threes as separate variables

```
class0 = np.where(data==0)
class1 = np.where(data==1)
class2 = np.where(data==2)
```

I knew how to write them in three lines as above.
However, what is the Pythonic way to do it using the examples below:

```
classes = ['class0', 'class1', 'class2']
values =[0,1,2]

for x, y in zip(classes, values):
    x = np.where(data == y)
    print x
```

HERE how can I name the answers resulted by x as class0,class1,class2???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary:

```
classes = ['class0', 'class1', 'class2']
values =[0,1,2]
output = {} #create a dictionary instance

for x, y in zip(classes, values):
    output[x] = np.where(data == y) #use the class name as the dictionary key
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do this if you really want three variables instead of a dictionary:

```
class0, class1, class2 = [np.where(data == i) for i in range(0, 3)]
```

This does not fit in the example you gave in the question though.